Json in POST HttpRequest Apex Class
I am new to coding (Apex and JSON) and I am trying to include a my apex class that I got from a JSON to Apex generator in an HttpRequest Class POST Method but I'm confused on some of it. Would someone please help me customized my class to include JSON class?
Here is my class generated from JSON:
public class httpCalloutJson {
    public String CompanyCode; 
    public String WorkerName; 
    public String AccountNumber; 
    public Boolean UseWarrantyAccount; // true
    public String ShippingWhs; // "06"
    public Boolean FreightCovered; // true
    public String CaseNumber; // "Case12345"
    public String ReferenceNumber; // "PO-12345"
    public String WarrantyReason; 
    public String ContactName; 
    public String ContactEmail; 
    public String DlvAddressName;
    public String DlvAddressStreet; 
    public String DlvAddressZipcode; 
    public String DlvAddressCity;
    public String DlvAddressState;
    public String DlvAddressCountry;
    public String DlvNote; 
    public List<Lines> Lines;

    public class Lines {
        public String ItemNumber; // "CAMO-01-M1"
        public Integer Quantity; // 100
        public String Unit; // "EA"
        public String Description; // "Hidden End Cam (Universal Clamp)"
        public Integer DiscPercent; // 100
    }

    public static httpCalloutJson parse(String jsonString) {
        return (httpCalloutJson) JSON.deserialize(jsonString, httpCalloutJson.class);
    }
}


Class updated based on comments:
public class httpCalloutSample {

    HttpCalloutJson jsonPayload = new HttpCalloutJson();

    public httpCalloutSample() {
        jsonPayload.CompanyCode = '1700';
        jsonPayload.WorkerName = 'Bailey1';
        jsonPayload.AccountNumber = 'C0001';
        jsonPayload.UseWarrantyAccount = true;
        jsonPayload.ShippingWhs = '06';
        jsonPayload.FreightCovered = true;
        jsonPayload.CaseNumber = 'Case1';
        jsonPayload.ReferenceNumber = 'PO-12345';
        jsonPayload.WarrantyReason = 'Camo-Replacement';
        jsonPayload.ContactName = 'Test Person';
        jsonPayload.ContactEmail = 'test.person@company.com';
        jsonPayload.DlvAddressName = 'Test Installer';
        jsonPayload.DlvAddressStreet = 'Installerstreet 20';
        jsonPayload.DlvAddressZipcode = '994455';
        jsonPayload.DlvAddressCity = 'New York';
        jsonPayload.DlvAddressState = 'NY';
        jsonPayload.DlvAddressCountry = 'USA';
        jsonPayload.DlvNote = 'Deliver add dock 22';

        jsonPayload.lines = new List<HttpCalloutJson.Lines>();
        HttpCalloutJson.Lines line1 = new HttpCalloutJson.Lines();
        line1.ItemNumber = 'CAMO-01-M1';
        line1.Quantity = 100;
        line1.Unit = 'EA';
        line1.Description = 'Universal Clamp';
        line1.DiscPercent = 100;
        jsonPayload.lines.add(line1);

        // JSON.serialize converts the Apex object into JSON
        String strJson = JSON.serialize(jsonPayload);

    // Instantiate a new Http object
    Http h = new Http();

    // Instantiate a new HTTP request
    // Specify request properties such as the endpoint, the POST method, etc. 
    HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
    req.setEndpoint('callout:WarrantyIntegrationAPI');  //my Named Credential
    req.setMethod('POST');
    req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    req.setBody(strJson);
        
    // Send the request, and return a response
    HttpResponse res = h.send(req);
    return;
  }
}



If you have some knowledge about "Object-Oriented Programming" already, then the Apex Basics & Database module on Trailhead would be a good place to start. That should help clear up basic issues in your code like not having the code inside of a method and the req.setBody(...) line being incorrect.

Beyond that, are you getting this JSON as the result of another callout, or do you mean to say that you need help figuring out how to make your own JSON payload (with the help of that class from the JSON2Apex tool)?

The JSON I received from my integration team, and used that in the JSON2Apex tool, so I think the 2nd one (how to make my own JSON payload and include that in the req.setBody of my httpCalloutSample class.

Look into External Services, it helps with external API integration without you writing code. You want the flow that starts with JSON - see doc for an example

A Quick OOP Intro
Not a substitution for a proper course on the programming paradigm, but...

Things in the world are modeled as "objects" (e.g. a cat, food, a lightbulb, etc...), which in Apex are defined using the class keyword
Those objects have information about them that we can store as variables (e.g. a given Car's color)
Objects also have methods (or functions, just two names for the same thing) that perform some work on instances of those objects (e.g. the send() method of the Http class causes Salesforce to actually send the request to the target url)
Methods can have 0 or more arguments in a well-defined order, which is just another way of saying "pass data into the method, so the method can use it"
Methods have a return type, which is the type of object/data you get back after the method finishes running
We use dot-notation . to access variables and run methods of an object (e.g. myCar.color = 'red';, myLightbulb.turnOn();)

So how do I make some JSON using that class that was generated?
By creating a new instance of the class (using the new keyword)
then using dot-notation to set the values for its variables
// Usually, by convention, class names start with an upper-case letter
// Apex is unusual in that it's mostly case-insensitive, but it's not a good idea to
//   make that a habit.
// It'll come back to haunt you if you ever work in pretty much any other language if
//   you do (like, say, Javascript for making a Lightning Web Component)

// Variables are declared like <Class name> <variable name>;
HttpCalloutJson jsonPayload;

// You need to initialize the variable before you can use it.
// Here, we'd use the `new` keyword to make a new instance of `HttpCalloutJson`
// This calls the class/object's "constructor"
// Salesforce provides a basic, no-argument constructor as long as no constructors are
//   explicitly defined for the class
jsonPayload = new HttpCalloutJson();

// You could also combine the variable declaration and initialization into a single line like
//HttpCalloutJson jsonPayload = new HttpCalloutJson();

// Now that you have initialized the variable, use dot-notation to access a variable
//   and use `=` to set a value.
// By convention, variable and method names start with a lower-case letter
jsonPayload.companyCode = '1234';
jsonPayload.accountNumber = '555';

// 'lines' is a list (one of the 3 "collection" types Apex has) of another class
// Setting the value there is similar, but different.
// To use an inner class (a class defined inside of another class) outside of the containing
//   class, we need to use <outer class>.<inner class>
// The class name inside of the angle braces tells Salesforce what type of stuff the List
//   will contain
jsonPayload.lines = new List<HttpCalloutJson.Lines>();

// You'll need to do something similar to make individual instances of `Lines` so that you
//   can add them to the list using .add()
HttpCalloutJson.Lines firstLine = new HttpCalloutJson.Lines();
firstLine.itemNumber = 'CAMO-01-M1';

jsonPayload.lines.add(firstLine);

Once you have all of that set up, turning it into JSON is as simple as passing jsonPayload into JSON.serialize() (which is a "static" method, which means we can call it just by using the class name instead of needing an instance of the class)
// other code omitted
// Note that the semicolon is always the last thing on lines of code
// Stuff like class and method declarations don't get semicolons
req.setBody(JSON.serialize(jsonPayload));

(Basically) all code needs to appear in a method
There are some exceptions, but the above statement is true 99% of the time
We can't (usually) have code just free-floating inside of a class
public class InvalidCode {
    system.debug('I\'m in danger!');
    Integer twoTimesTwo = 2 * 2;
}

It needs to be contained in a method
public class ValidCode {
    public void calculateTwoTimesTwo() {
        system.debug('Inside of a method, so we\'re fine');
        Integer twoTimesTwo = 2 * 2;
    }
}


Thank you @derek that is extremely helpful. I've updated my class with your comments in mind but I am getting an error: Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void setBody(httpCalloutJson) from the type System.HttpRequest (46:9)

Also I took a look at external services, but I dont have an API spec to import. Where would I get that?

please disregard error message I figured out my issue (use strJson instead of jsonpayload in setBody property.
